# How to customize "The password confirmation does not match." error message?

Tags: laravel, validation, localization

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-customizing-the-error-messages), `error messages` can be customized inside `lang/en/validation.php` but the error message I am receiving is not present in the file:

```
The password confirmation does not match.
```

I receive the error message when failing `validation` because `$request->password_confirmation` is different from the`$request->password`:

```
$request->validate([
    'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
]);
```

How can I customize the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rules = [
    'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()]
];

$customMessages = [
    'password.confirmed' => 'The :attribute does not match' // change it at here
];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Rule `confirmed` The field under validation must have a matching
field of `{field}_confirmation`.
For example, if the field under validation is `password`,
a matching `password_confirmation` field must be present in the input.

Comment: It should be `'password.confirmed'` for password only.

Comment: yup, thanks for this , I'll edit

Comment: Thank you, it works. This version is a tad shorter `$request->validate($rules, $customMessages);`.